# How to filter collection for json data field in magento2?

Tags: magento2, collection

Have any function or way we can directly filter json data in magento2?

like:

brand: {"product":"test","purchase":"500"}

if i want to filter more than purchased 500 times in magento2 have any easy way?

Comment: please check with - http://jsbin.com/yakubixi/4/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It's js... i want in php
And this question for magento buit in functions. i have diffrent many custom ways but just i want to know is do we Have any default functionality like this?

Answer (score 1):

Use below for your collection:

$collection->getSelect()->where('JSON_CONTAINS(brand, '[?]')', test);